# WordPress subdomain matches to another page using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, server

I have a WordPress website with many retailer account and all of them can view their profile on their own subdomain.
Like retailer 'aaa' -> aaa.domain.com

I want this aaa.domain.com to match to a page - www.domain.com/page and get the content without changing the url.

Earlier it was working but after auto upgradation of WordPress ver., htaccess got modified all the rules are erased.

please help me with this.

Regards.

Comment: Restore .htaccess file from backup? You keep backups of your server right?

Comment: No actually all the backup was taken using a WordPress plugin, and I can't found the htaccess in it.